# Why am I receiving and IOException: PDF header signature not found when creating a PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I trying to create a PDF file with empty pages, but the code throws `java.io.IOException: P
PDF header signature not found` when I'm trying to read the temp file.  Why?

Relevant code:

```
Document testDoc = new Document();
File testFile = File.createTempFile("pdfTemp", ".tmp");
String test = testFile.getName();
PdfWriter testWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(test));
testDoc.open();
for (int x=1; x<=pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); x++){
    testWriter.setPageEmpty(false);
    testDoc.newPage();
}
testDoc.close();
PdfReader testReader = new PdfReader(test);
```

Comment: What is the value returned by `pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()`?

Comment: it depends, i'm getting the number of pages from another pdf file. usually its around 30

Comment: You do realize `testDoc` and `testWriter` have no correlation based on your code here, right?  Did you mean to use `testDoc` where you used `document`?

Comment: oh wow how did miss that. thanks for the help. i'm gonna change it and see if error is gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a coding issue.  Your code uses

```
PdfWriter testWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(test));
```

but `document` variable isn't declared anywhere.  I suspect you meant to use the following instead:

```
PdfWriter testWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(testDoc, new FileOutputStream(test));
```